# How do change the size of input box?

Tags: html, css, checkbox, textbox

I'm using this css file but one thing that is annoying me is the css file is making the input a bit to big.

http://jsfiddle.net/fcfku/ and go under "Show Advance Options".

How do I set the size? Also for the check box (for the TOS), how can I change the check image?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following rules have to be adjusted:

```
input, textarea, select {
    /*line-height*/
    font: 12px/1.5 'Open Sans', 'Lucida Sans Unicode', 'Lucida Grande', sans-serif;
    /*possibly excessive padding*/
    padding: 5px 10px;
}

input, select {
    /*height applied to too many elements*/
    height: 30px;
}
```

Also, the css reset should be applied *first* i.e. before any other rules

Comment: Thanks I'm going to play around with the numbers.

Comment: @LearningC: that would be easier if you used Firebug or Chrome inspector - you could toggle and adjust rules without having to reload the page and rewrite the css etc.

Comment: Oh that didn't know you can do that with Firegbug. I was using Chrome inspector but not really good at it. This would save me a lot of time.